# How do you cancel a specific alarm manager after app is restarted?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that, after receiving a text from a certain number, starts a repeating alarm using AlarmManager.  The AlarmReciever plays an alarm sound for thirty seconds and then the alarm repeats every five minutes.  I want to cancel the AlarmManager when the app is closed and restarted by the user but I have to use the same instance of the alarmIntent to cancel it.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to use the same instance of the alarmIntent to cancel it.

No, you have to use an equivalent `PendingIntent` to cancel it. By "equivalent", I mean:

- It is the same operation (e.g., activity, service, broadcast)
- It has the same request code (2nd parameter to methods like `getActivity()`)
- It has an equivalent `Intent`

By "equivalent `Intent`", I mean that all the routing information is the same (component, action, data, MIME type, categories). Extras do not matter.

You need to hold onto enough information in a persistent data store (e.g., file) to be able to create an equivalent `PendingIntent` to pass to `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`.